# Empty search redirect to Home page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-search

I am using Drupal 7 and my `search functionality` is not working properly.

When I click on search button without enter any `keyword` it redirects to `home page` with showing the message `Please enter some keywords`. and same thing happens when there is `no result` found for the respective `search keyword`.

So can anyone please guide me how can I redirect the empty search to search page?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

That's not normal behavior, so you did something to mess it up. Try first temporary switching to some standard Drupal theme instead of yours and see will that still happen. If not - problem is in your theme.

If it still happens try turning off modules one by one and see will it start working normally without some module.